# Postgres 14 manual install on RedHat 8

Tags: postgresql, centos, redhat

I am trying to install Postgres 14 on a computer with no internet access:

sudo dnf install postgresql14-14.2-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64.rpm

Error:
Problem: conflicting requests
nothing provides libreadline.so.6()(64bit) needed by postgresql14-14.2-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)

RedHat 8 comes with libreadline.so.7 and does not let me install redline 6. I created a symlink with ln -s libreadline.so.7.0 libreadline.so.6, but still getting the same error.

Do you have any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using a package for RH7 if you're using RedHat 8?

Answer (score 0):

Mat, you are right! I got postgresql14-14.2-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64.rpm installed. Thanks a lot!